# Noun form of "affected", meaning things that are affected by X

Tags: single-word-requests

Take the following simplified sentence:

> A,B and C are commonly affected by X.

If I want to formulate a sentence, where the message is to highlight A,B and C; so something like

> A, B and C are important because they are the common **affectees** of process X.

The word *affectee* does not exist in OED or any other dictionary I look at ([although it seems to be used in literature very rarely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=affectee&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caffectee%3B%2Cc0)). Is there a better word for this purpose?

I am OK with using a synonym, so the word does not need to  stem from *affect*.

Comment: This may well be a lexical gap. The workaround 'A, B and C are important here because they are they are things common affected by process X' shows that this is not a vast problem.

Comment: "Common affectees" could mean those things affected together or not all, incidentally.   "Affected" could be used as a plural noun, though.  To make it even less clear, just to insist on using the verb *to be*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought so (re:lexical gap).. Thanks for the suggestion but this will go into my doctoral thesis, so I'd like to avoid using words like "things". I feel I need to be more specific somehow..

Comment: @stevesliva well, I admit the word _common_ might be misleading there, but that's besides the point. "_ultimate affectees_" work to same effect for my use case. I don't follow the other half of your comment, how do you suggest I use "_affected_" as a noun?

Comment: Did I really leave 2 mistakes in that comment? A superfluous 'they are' and a missing 'ly'.  However, a workaround is always needed to bridge a lexical gap. And if you don't specify A, B, C and X, it's impossible for answerers to be more specific than 'things'.

Comment: @posdef, I meant that in order to avoid saying, "because they are commonly affected by," (adj) I find myself mooting, "because they are the most common affected of" (plural noun).  My gripe with that path is that we make it less clear, and I don't have any issue with where we started from...

Answer (score 2):

I think that **subject** would work in such a sentence:

```
A, B and C are important because they are the common subjects to process X.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few proposals to help you express your ideas in your thesis.

1. A, B and C are important because they are the common **reformates**
   of process X.  (Borrowed from chemistry.)
2. A, B and C are important because they are **simultaneously
   affected** by process X.
3. A, B and C are important because they are the common **processes**
   affected by X.  (I don't know if A, B and C are processes, but
   whatever they are, that's the word to put after "common.")
4. A, B and C are important because they are the common **products** of
       process X.
5. Modelling your situation as a directed graph could be helpful.  Draw
   a directed graph with arrows going from X to A, X to B, and X to C. 
           Explain that an arrow pointing from vertex P to vertex Q will mean
           that process P *affects* process Q.  Then you can say that A, B and
           C are important because they are the **terminal vertices** of X.

Answer (score 0):

When the process has good outcomes, we say "beneficiaries" and when it has bad outcomes, we say "casualties", but these are value-laden.  For neutral words, you could try maths or computer science.

Comment: how do you mean "_you could try maths or computer science_"?

Comment: @posdef - I think he means to try those StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

The word "CONSEQUENT"  may be used which means something which results logically from the antecedent.

"Resultant" or "effect" can also be used to effectively convey the intended meaning.

__A, B,  & C are important because they are the common consequences/ effects/results(resultants) of process X.

Of course, if the intended message is to suffer the effect of resultant consequence, not the result, it is better to use the phrase, "enjoying/suffering consequences.